# cloning github project from eclipse

Tags: android, git, github, egit

here's my situation. 
First off, i started developing for Android a couple of days ago using AIDE in my Galaxy S2. 
All good, created a GitHub repository where i commit and push all my files.

Now, i've downloaded the Eclipse Android SDK Bundle with the EGit plugin in it.
After cloning my github project, i'm not able to compile/run my app from Eclipse.

Is there a way for me to be able to do that? Tried to use the "Use Wizard Project blalba" but i don't know what else to do, i couldn't do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work in other environments? in the old environment? If you clone it in other machine, does it work?

Comment: I'm gonna try to clone it in my office's pc and let you know, but i don't know if i'm doing it correctly. Is okey to use the "Clone project"?

Comment: My suggestion is to forget Egit and start using the console `git clone /project/url/`

Comment: yeah, seen that. But how do i use the console? :(

Comment: The firs step is to download it and install it ;) and then use it :)

Comment: Yeah, but i don't know what console are you talking about.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: "After cloning my github project, i'm not able to compile/run my app from Eclipse." Can you elaborate on that? What is the error message?